# CMD Run as admin yields "Windows Cannot access Specified device, path, or file"

Tags: windows, command-line, uac

For some reason when I run cmd as administrator
This happens: [image: Error]

However if I run cmd normally (unprivledged) or if I disable UAC completely, command prompt pops up normally.
**SFC** and **check disk** did not detect any errors

Anyone know what's going on ?

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: No it does not occur in safe mode

Answer (score 0):

As booting in Safe Mode fixed the problem, this indicates
that some third-party application is responsible for it.

To locate the problematic application, you may use the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

This utility shows all programs configured to run during system bootup or login
in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them later with another click. You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*,
*Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*

I would suggest turning off startup entries in bunches, drilling down to the startup
program that causes this behavior. Once identified, it might have some setting
that can avoid the problem, or can be left out of startup and only be invoked
when required (verify that once invoked it does not add another startup
entry, but such can again be disabled by Autoruns).

Comment: Weird I've turn off all entries and it's still happenning

Comment: Weird. Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) including the DISM commands in the linked article.

Comment: Did that, no corruption detected.

Comment: There might be some problem with permissions. A [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) might fix it. This is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade, so treat it similarly.

Comment: I might just restore from a backup image this is dragging on for too long.

Comment: That's certainly an option if you have such a backup. If this is a relatively recent problem and System Restore is enabled, you could rollback to before the problem occurred; this is a softer method.

Comment: Yeah I'd say so too. I figured out why it was happenning as well, I was trying to access another user account's Documents folder from an external harddrive through CMD running as administrator and then after that happenned still don't have a clue on how to solve it though except restoring from a full disk image Backup

Comment: What did you do to access that folder? Did you change anything in the registry?

Comment: No I didn't change anything in the registry